# Negating a word within a line using regular expression

Tags: xml, regex, xpath, xsd, grep

Given the this expression that matches lines that contain *minOccurs*

`<xs:element[^>]+?\sminOccurs\s*=[^>]+>`

and this text:

```
<xs:element name="shipto">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="city" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="country" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

how do I change it from matching *xs:element* lines that *contain minOccurs* to *xs:element* lines that *don't contain minOccurs*.

The output expected would be this:

```
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
```

Comment: Using an XML parser instead of regex to parse XML would work do _exactly_ as you've asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use XML engine instead of regex. Appropriate XPath:

```
//xs:element[not(@minOccurs)]
```

Regex:

```
<xs:element(?![^>]+?minOccurs=".*?")[^>]*>
```